# MySQL SP - Percona 5.6 official on Centos 7 - temp table empty at different times after being populated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Given this table:

```
create table test (id varchar(36) not null default '');
```

populated by

```
insert into test set id = '04d513a1-738a-11e7-a698-2025640c3931';
insert into test set id = '048df10c-738a-11e7-a698-2025640c3931';
insert into test set id = 'ffa685c2-7389-11e7-a698-2025640c3931';
```

can anyone explain why a temp table created from this data is null at different times in an SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_fixCdrSrc`()
BEGIN

Declare lCount int;
Declare lId varchar(36);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpCDRid;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpCDRid (cdrId varchar(36)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

insert into tmpCDRid
select id from test;

select count(1) from tmpCDRid into lCount;

WHILE lCount > 0 DO 
    select * from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;               

    select 'Value: ',lId;

    delete from tmpCDRid where cdrId = lId;     

    set lcount = lcount - 1;
END WHILE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpCDRid;
END
```

If I do

```
select * from tmpCDRid
```

just above

```
WHILE lCount > 0 DO
```

I get the three items inserted, and they are returned, so the temp table tmpCDRid is most definitely populated - a select on it returns the items.

However, output from this SP is

```
+---------+------+
| Value:  | lId  |
+---------+------+
| Value:  | NULL |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.26 sec)


+---------+------+
| Value:  | lId  |
+---------+------+
| Value:  | NULL |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.24 sec)


+---------+------+
| Value:  | lId  |
+---------+------+
| Value:  | NULL |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)
```

Why?

If I do this in the SP

```
select * from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;
```

lId is null... most of the time!

If I add

```
select * from tmpCDRid
```

just above

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpCDRid;
```

all the data is still there in the tmpCDRid table and is returned correctly.

So the SP literally cannot "find" any data in the temp table if selecting INTO a variable of the same type, in the loop.

Outside the loop it CAN find the data in the temp table, if selecting to console.

I changed this line

select * from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;

into

select id from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;

and it works for one or two iterations of the sp, e. g. output changes to

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| Value:  | lId                                  |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| Value:  | 04d513a1-738a-11e7-a698-2025640c3931 |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)
```

which is correct behaviour.

But after three or four calls to the SP it changes (with no change to the SP) back to returning null.

Changing this line

```
select id from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;
```

will start working for about three or four iterations - lId is not null, then it will go back to being null.

Then it remains like that, e. g.

```
select * from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;
```

returns lId as NULL, until I restart my MySQL server instance...

Then it is back to the same flip-flopping - e. g. three or four times the one "ID way" of getting data from the temp table WILL work in side the loop, then three or four times the "* way" of getting data from the temp table will work inside the loop, then it simply stops working completely and I get null until the server instance is restarted.

Anybody got ANY idea what is going on here?

I get the same behaviour on a Percona 5.7 instance on a different Centos 7 machine, and exactly the same behaviour on a Windows instance of MySQL 5.6.

Thx!

Comment: Unfortunately I could not reproduce your case [demo](http://rextester.com/CNDE97072). Anyway try to avoid `*` and check if `select cdrId from tmpCDRid limit 1 into lId;` help in any way. Second thought is to add `ORDER BY` clause to limit.